# Minimizing API calls using GraphQL and React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I’ve written an API in GraphQL ([Apollo Server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/)), and a separate application in React (Utilizing [Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/)). The app itself is really straight forward and doesn't require many calls to the API at all, and because of GraphQL, I can get all of the data a user needs in 2 calls and the only time I need to refetch the data is after a mutation.

I have a signin and a signup mutation, then two more mutations for creating an updating the main object a user interacts with.

I'm fairly familiar with React and GraphQL, but I feel like there has to be a way to make one 'larger' call after the signin/signup mutation that fetches all the data user a needs, rather than making a call to each level of nesting based on the loading of a particular component.

**Mutations**

- SignUp
- SignIn
- CreateShirt
- UpdateShirt

**Queries**

- GetShirts
- GetDesigns

Ideally, I could utilize a query similar to

```
query GetUser {
  user {
    id
    email
    shirts {
      id
      style
      design {
        name
        swatch
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So.. I could return all of this information in the SignIn / SignUp mutations but then after the UpdateShirt mutation, I don't have a (named) query that I can force to refetch. So then I leaned towards just creating a `GetUser` query that I could refetch but I don't know where to call it from.. it isn't specific to a component necessarily, more to a status of authentication.

What is the most efficient way to query my API for this information? Ignoring the ability to make nested queries and make the components ask for it seems silly.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you are lookin for?

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#refetching-queries

After calling the mutation, this way, you can re-fetch your queries.

```
// Refetches two queries after mutation completes
const [addTodo, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(ADD_TODO, {
  refetchQueries: [
    {query: GET_POST}, // DocumentNode object parsed with gql
    'GetComments' // Query name
  ],
});
```

However, if you want **one request** then that means what you are lookin for is **Batching**.

You can batch multiple queries, something like:

```
const { data } = useQuery(gql`
query ShameelQuery {
  query1
  query2
}
`)
```

You can find more details in their official docs:
https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/performance/batching-client-graphql-queries/

Comment: The refetch yes, but it’s more.. where does the query live that I refetch?

Comment: You have to define the queries in your codebase. Either in same file or preferably in other files and then import it where you want to call it.

Comment: I understand that. One of my issues with React is that all of the libraries' examples show you the simple way of doing things, like -- yes, `useQuery` is great, and it works well, but how to best utilize that hook in an application is more difficult. Just like `useReactiveVar`, it just shows it being used, presumably within a component but where should `createReactiveVar` be? In a component? In App.js? Same goes for my question, I know how to query the API, but the information that comes back can be shared across all components, so it seems silly to make that query in all of them.

Comment: If you want to share the same information in entire app then either you should use `Redux` or you should use `Context` for global data sharing..